# append() заменят элементы в списке, а не добавляет их

Tags: python

Есть код на Python

```
name_dict = {}

def thesaurus(*name):
    for i in name:
        first_vowel = i[0:1]
        name_dict[first_vowel] = []
        name_dict[first_vowel].append(i)
    print(name_dict)

thesaurus('Юлия', "Николай", "Юрий", "Сергей", "Никита", "Савелий")
```

На выходе должно получиться это:

```
{'Ю': ['Юрий', 'Юлия'], 'Н': ['Никита', 'Николай'], 'С': ['Савелий', 'Сергей']}
```

А получается это:

```
{'Ю': ['Юрий'], 'Н': ['Никита'], 'С': ['Савелий']}
```

Вместо того, чтобы добавить новый элемент в список, функция append() заменяет предыдущее значение с каждым новым циклом.

Хотелось бы понять причину этого явления, а заодно и получить правильный код.

P.S. Это мой первый вопрос на данном сайте, если я что-то сделал неправильно, не ругайте сильно!

Comment: А чего вы хотите, если вы каждый раз очищаете список `name_dict[first_vowel] = []` прежде чем добавить очередной элемент.

Comment: Проблема не в функции append, а в том, что перед ее вызовом переинициализируется список слов `name_dict[first_vowel] = []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант:

```
def my_func(names: list) -> dict:
    name_dict = {}
    for name in names:
        name_dict[name[0]] = []
    for name in names:
        name_dict[name[0]].append(name)

    return name_dict


my_func(['Юлия', "Николай", "Юрий", "Сергей", "Никита", "Савелий"])
```

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы обнуляете список. Из за этого в него попадают только последние имена:

```
name_dict[first_vowel] = []
name_dict[first_vowel].append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Специально для иницилизации новых ключей есть [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
def thesaurus(*name):
    name_dict = {}
    for i in name:
        name_dict.setdefault(i[0], []).append(i)
    print(name_dict)


thesaurus('Юлия', "Николай", "Юрий", "Сергей", "Никита", "Савелий")
```

> ```
> {'Ю': ['Юлия', 'Юрий'], 'Н': ['Николай', 'Никита'], 'С': ['Сергей', 'Савелий']}
> ```

Другой инструмент [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections


def thesaurus(*name):
    name_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i in name:
        name_dict[i[0]].append(i)
    print(name_dict)


thesaurus('Юлия', "Николай", "Юрий", "Сергей", "Никита", "Савелий")
```

> ```
> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Ю': ['Юлия', 'Юрий'], 'Н': ['Николай', 'Никита'], 'С': ['Сергей', 'Савелий']})
> ```

Если вы не хотите использовать ничего специального, проверяйте что ключ уже есть в словаре и, если его нет, создавайте:

```
def thesaurus(*name):
    name_dict = {}
    for i in name:
        key = i[0]
        if key not in name_dict:
            name_dict[key] = []
        name_dict[key].append(i)
    print(name_dict)


thesaurus('Юлия', "Николай", "Юрий", "Сергей", "Никита", "Савелий")
```

> ```
> {'Ю': ['Юлия', 'Юрий'], 'Н': ['Николай', 'Никита'], 'С': ['Сергей', 'Савелий']}
> ```

И ещё один вариант, на крохотную долю быстрее. Я его меньше люблю из-за дублирования функциональности:

```
def thesaurus(*name):
    name_dict = {}
    for i in name:
        key = i[0]
        if key in name_dict:
            name_dict[key].append(i)
        else:
            name_dict[key] = [i]
    print(name_dict)


thesaurus('Юлия', "Николай", "Юрий", "Сергей", "Никита", "Савелий")
```

> ```
> {'Ю': ['Юлия', 'Юрий'], 'Н': ['Николай', 'Никита'], 'С': ['Сергей', 'Савелий']}
> ```

Все примеры выше смешивают частную функциональность (какие ключи и значения для телефонной книги) и общую (из пар ключ/значение сделать словарь списков). Будет правильно их разделить, общая функциональнось в функции `multidict`.  `thesaurus` подготавливает данные и обращается к `multidict`:

```
def multidict(items):
    md = {}
    for k, v in items:
        md.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return md


def thesaurus(*name):
    name_dict = multidict((i[0], i) for i in name)
    print(name_dict)


thesaurus('Юлия', "Николай", "Юрий", "Сергей", "Никита", "Савелий")
```

> ```
> {'Ю': ['Юлия', 'Юрий'], 'Н': ['Николай', 'Никита'], 'С': ['Сергей', 'Савелий']}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
name_dict = {}

def thesaurus(*name):
    for i in name:
        first_vowel = i[0]
        if name_dict.get(first_vowel) == None:
            name_dict[first_vowel] = []
        name_dict[first_vowel].append(i)
    print(name_dict)

thesaurus('Юлия', "Николай", "Юрий", "Сергей", "Никита", "Савелий")
```

Comment: `name_dict.get(first_vowel) == None` -> `first_vowel not in name_dict`.